# How do i find the cubic inches of this shape?

Tags: volume

I can solve for the cubic inches of a pyramid or a triangle, but this shape is a bit different as all sides do not come to one point. It is a triangular bag that i need to find the cubic inch size for.

How do i find the volume of this shape? Is it similar to solving for a pyramid?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [prism](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/solid-geometry/triangular-prism/formula-volume-triangular-prism.php).

The cross section is a triangle, find the area of the triangle and multiply by the depth and you get the volume.